# .bash_history file keeps showing up in current folder

Tags: bash

I have an Ubuntu server on which I use zsh. Recently, I noticed after a few commands, .bash_history shows up. I remove it, and a few commands later, it's back. This started recently, and I don't know what caused it or how to stop it.

Comment: What's the value of your $HISTFILE variable?

Comment: @glennjackman `/home/(me)/.zsh_history`

Comment: What is the contents of the bash history file?